# Why are attribute classes in Json.Net sealed?

Tags: c#, json.net, sealed

Is there any spesific reason why e.g. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonIgnoreAttribute is a sealed class? The reason I ask is because I'd like to make wrapper around the Json.Net calls, so that the assembly ref is in one assembly only (makes updating the assembly and testing a bit easier).

Comment: I'm not sure how far along you are in your project but have you ever looked at using http://json.codeplex.com/ library as your json api?

Comment: This is the API we're using, yes. The 'Json.Net' referes to Newtonsoft.Json up on json.codeplex.com, and the JsonIgnoreAttribute is a class in this library.

Comment: Check this answer to see why making custom .Net attribute classes `sealed` is considered a security and performance best practice:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7868218/406903

Answer (score 1):

Because generally that implies they have (or serve) no purpose being extended/specialized (like many attribute types that exists in the .NET BCL).

Comment: For attribute types in the BCL I can see that being a valid reason as one would have references to the .Net-assemblies in pretty much any project. For 3rd party libs it's another story though; I'd really prefer to only reference these assemblies from ONE place, so that I can easily upgrade / switch to another library if needed.