# Why is .Net best practice to design custom attributes as sealed?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes

I'm reading *Pro C# 2010 and the .Net 4 Platform* by Andrew Troelsen.

In Chapter 15 about Attributes exists a note:

> **Note:** For security reasons, it is considered a .Net best practice to design all custom attributes as sealed.

The author doesn't explain why, can someone explain why?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> CA1813: Avoid unsealed attributes:
>   The .NET Framework class library provides methods for retrieving
>   custom attributes. By default, these methods search the attribute
>   inheritance hierarchy; for example Attribute.GetCustomAttribute
>   searches for the specified attribute type, or any attribute type that
>   extends the specified attribute type. Sealing the attribute eliminates
>   the search through the inheritance hierarchy, and can improve
>   performance.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1813-avoid-unsealed-attributes

Attributes are simply metadata discovered at runtime. As it is quoted, if someone else derives from your custom attribute class, by default .NET will find them too, which may imply a security risk if the derived attribute class is modifying the behavior of your original attribute in a way to you never intended to.

Even though performance is the prime reason to seal attribute classes, here is a [formidable article dealing with its security side](https://web.archive.org/web/20091225203451/http://alabaxblog.info/?p=44).

Comment: @TeomanSoygul About performance: I can call `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` and pass false as parameter to eliminates the search through the inheritance hierarchy: `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(false)`

Comment: @AcazSouza, that's different. The `inherit` parameter controls whether ancestors of the element you're querying should be searched. That is, whether base types should be checked too. It doesn't restrict whether derived attribute types are included in the results however.

Answer (score 7):

There is one more reason to seal attributes.

Consider the following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class Attr1 : Attribute
{
}
```

Here you allow only single attribute decoration: `AllowMultiple = false`

Compiler won't allow this:

```
[Attr1]
[Attr1]
public class Foo
{
}
```

Later in your code you can safely call `memberInfo.GetCustomAttribute()` which will throw `AmbiguousMatchException` if more then one attribute of the given type was found.

Let's now inherit:

```
public class Attr2 : Attr1
{
}
```

Now compiler is silent.

```
[Attr1]
[Attr2]
public class Foo
{
}
```

So if later somebody inherits from your attribute and passes back to your code some entity marked with both attributes unexpected exception will be thrown.

Full example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        typeof(Foo).GetCustomAttribute<Attr1>();
    }

    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class Attr1 : Attribute
    {
    }

    public class Attr2 : Attr1
    {
    }

    [Attr1]
    [Attr2]
    public class Foo
    {
    }

    [Attr1]
    public class Bar : Foo
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) just says:

> **DO** seal custom attribute classes, if possible. This makes the look-up for the attribute faster.

I didn't see anything about security in that section, but @Teoman Soygul makes a good point. So I'd agree with Mr. Troelsen.