# Use int constant in attribute

Tags: c#, constants

Can anybody explain why I can't use a const Int32 in an C# attribute?

Example:

```
private const Int32 testValue = 123;  
[Description("Test: " + testValue)]  
public string Test { get; set; }
```

Makes the compiler say:

> "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, ..."

Why?

Comment: It's probably the order of execution. The int you've defined will likely not be instantiated at the time the attribute runs.

Comment: If expreession would be allowed it should be calculated at compile type. As you know C# compiler dont support it.

Comment: @AlexanderBalte: Actually, the compiler can calculate expressions at compile-time.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the error states, an attribute argument must be a *constant* expression.

Concatenating a string and an integer is not a constant expression.

Thus, if you pass `"Test: " + 123` directly, it will give the same error.
On the other hand, if you change `testValue` to a string, it will compile.

---

### Explanation

The rules for constant expressions state that a constant expression can contain arithmetic operators, provided that both operands are themselves constant expressions.

Therefore, `"A" + "B"` is still constant.

However, `"A" + 1` uses the `string operator +(string x, object y);`, in which the integer operand is boxed to an object.
The constant-expression rules explicitly state that

> Other conversions including boxing, unboxing and implicit reference conversions of non-null values are not permitted in constant expressions.

Comment: So there's no way to use Integers in Attributes which expect a string?

Comment: @Sascha: Correct, AFAIK.  You could make your own attribute class that inherits that one and calls `ToString()` on its argument before passing to `base()`.

Comment: @SLaks good suggestions, assuming of course that the attribute is not `sealed`...

Comment: @SLaks good suggestions, assuming of course that the attribute is not sealed. Which is a problem because sealing attributes is the best practice (for good reasons): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868218/why-is-net-best-practice-to-design-custom-attributes-as-sealed

Answer (score 3):

'+' operator between int and string causes invocation of ToString method of int which is not "Compile time constant". It is like this

```
private const int x = 3;
private const string s = x.ToString(); // cannot be done
```

Comment: That's not quite true; it actually compiles to `String.Concat(str, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

You can only pass compile time evaluated constants including result of `typeof()` operators and excluding `decimal`s into `Attribute`s constructors