# Why can't assign a constant string to a constant string type?

Tags: c#, string

As far as I know the concatenation of `"H" + 'i'` produce a constant string.
Am I or C# wrong ?

Code :

```
const string b = "H" + 'i';
// Error : The expression being assigned to 'b' must be constant
```

Does this count as a bug or a feature ?

Comment: You're not adding two strings, but a string and a char.

Comment: A char is not a string literal, hence it's not a constant. This will work: `const string b = "H" + "
i";`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a subtlety.

`'i'` is a **char** literal.
Adding it to a string involves a boxing conversion (to call `string operator +(string x, object y)`, as specified in the spec), which is not a constant expression.

For more information, see my [earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14244846/34397).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the VS2010 error will help define it:

```
Constant initializer must be compile-time constant
```

so "H" + 'i' is a runtime value.

Comment: That doesn't explain why.  `"H" + "i"` is fine.

Comment: @SLaks, true, I liked your "earlier answer" which explained it in depth.