# MVC Set Value To Require ErrorMessage Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have `Model` with `properties` with `Require` `attribute`. I also have `resource` file which I store some values. The idea is to use the resource file as values to `attribute property parameter`. But the following error message is thrown **Error 1   An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type Credentials.cs**. Any idea what is the problem and how to solve it ?

Example:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = STT.Properties.Resources.Require_Username)]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to use resources in required attribute:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Require_Username", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(STT.Properties.Resources))]
```

Comment: It is working now. What was the problem ?

Comment: You can't pass directly a non constant value to an attribute, so you need to use, in this case, `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` to pass resource value. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244784/use-int-constant-in-attribute) you can find more info.